# Equivalence of two maximization problems

Tags: optimization, expectation

I am looking for any way to prove the equivalence of these two maximization problems
$$
\mathop{\mathrm{argmax}}_{\mathbf{\lambda}} \mathbb{E}_{X}\Big[\sum_n^N a_n\log_2(X(\mathbf{k};\theta)))\Big] \triangleq \mathop{\mathrm{argmax}}_{\mathbf{\lambda}} \sum_n^N a_n\log_2(\mathbb{E}_{X}[X(\mathbf{k};\theta)])
$$
where $a_n$ are always positive and $X$ is a r.v. which stands as a non-negative composition of random variables. The vector $\mathbf{k}$ has dimension $N$ and is made up by Poisson random variables the n-th of those has mean $\mathbb{E}[k_n]=\lambda_n$. $\theta$ is the set of random variables that compose $X$ but do not affect the realization of the other terms of the sum.

Please, note the second term of the equivalence is the application of Jensen's inequality to the left-hand side maximization. This leads to the fact that the objective's maximum can't be the same for the two problems. If the maximizers of the two problems are exactly the same optimum feasible set I have solve my issue.

Any hint is highly appreciated!

Comment: Since $\log_2$ is strictly increasing, they are equivalent.

Comment: @GNUSupporter thanks. I was thinking the same but was not totally sure btw. That means that by applying Jensen's inequality to each term, it leads to the same maximizers but not same objective maximum. right? Thanks a lot again

Comment: I agree with the use of Jensen's inequality to show that the objective maximum is not generally the same.

Comment: @GNUSupporter Ok, thanks anyway. The only think I need to know is if the application of Jensen's inequality to that sum preserves the optimum feasible set for the decision variables. If anyone can shed more light on my lack I would be grateful. Thanks!

Comment: @LinAlg It is a composition of random variables strongly nested inside _f(x)_, any attempt to make use of its distribution for the law of the unconscious statistician is of any help here

Comment: @LinAlg Thanks for the edit! They are dependent unfortunately.

Comment: @LinAlg sorry my bad, let me rephrase it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73836/discussion-between-emg-and-linalg).